# Routing в blueprints. Flask не находит страницу в папке templates

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Структура проекта

```
.
├── app.py
└── Project
    ├── login
    │   └── views.py
    ├── models
    └── templates
        └── login
            └── login_page.html
```

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from Project.login.views import login_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(login_blueprint, url_prefix='/auth')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### Project/login/views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

login_blueprint = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@login_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def show_login_page():
    return render_template("login_page.html")
```

При обращении по `127.0.0.1:5000/auth/` получаем

```
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: login_page.html
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2020 04:21:24] "GET /auth/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Пробовал указывать `template_folder` - не помогло, ровно как и переносить в другие папки `login_page.html`.

Как сделать так, чтобы jijna2 нашла этот шаблон?

Comment: Указать `template_folder` и `render_template("login/login_page.html")`

Comment: @andreymal, можно подробнее? :) Я пытался указывать `template_folder` - не помогло. Что там нужно указать?

Comment: Ещё раз, `render_template("login/login_page.html")`

Comment: @andreymal, я добавил `render_template("login/login_page.html")` - не помогло

Comment: А `template_folder` точно указывает на правильную папку `templates`?

Comment: @andreymal, я пробовал указывать `template_folder` на `templates`, на `templates/login` - не помогло. Куда она должна указывать при текущем строении проекта?

Comment: Ну например на `Project/templates`

Comment: @andreymal, Ух-ты, я разобрался, только немного по-другому :). нужно было переместить `templates` в папку `login`, и указать `template_folder="templates"`, `return render_template("login/login_page.html")`. Таким образом все работает

Comment: Пути считаются относительно текущей папки. Вы запускаете свой фласк внутри папки `Project/login` что ли?

Comment: @andreymal, нет, app.run() находится вне `Project`, как показано в вопросе

Comment: Значит `template_folder="Project/templates"` должен был нормально работать. Думается мне, вы что-то очень сильно недоговариваете

Comment: @andreymal, может конечно это и работает (я не пробовал), но логичнее было бы разбить проект на папочки по логике. Допустим, на авторизацию, к примеру, посты, и прочее. Это и сработало